Apex error: System.QueryException: unexpected token: 'Prospect'
I am not able to find the error in my code. It's showing as:

Line: 24, Column: 1 System.QueryException: unexpected token:
'Prospect'

String accountClass = 'Class';

String queryString = 'SELECT id, name, Phone, Rating From Account';

if(accountCLass == 'Class1'){
    queryString += 'WHERE Prospect Rating=\'hot\' AND Type=\'Prospect Rating\'';
}else if(accountCLass == 'Class2'){
    queryString += 'WHERE Prospect Rating=\'Warm\' AND Type=\'other\'';
}else{
    queryString += 'WHERE Prospect Rating=\'Hot\'';
}

List<Account> accounts = Database.query(queryString);
system.debug('accounts ' +accounts);
system.debug('accounts size '+accounts.size());


Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  You need to use field's API name in your query.  Prospect Rating is not a valid API name.

The field on Account is called Rating, however in your SOQL query you are referencing Prospect Rating. (This cannot be a field because field API names do not have spaces)
The query should look like:
queryString += ' WHERE Rating = \'hot\' AND Type = \'Prospect Rating\'';


Almost--there needs to be a whitespace before where.
